# How to configure other client redirect_uri's than '/sso/login' for Spring Boot client app?

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, keycloak

I would like to avoid the default '/sso/login' redirect uri but instead be able to configure custom redirect URIs for my Spring Boot application.

I have added several redirect URI's in [image: client configuration in Keycloak Admin console] ("/sso/login" added only because it won't work otherwise right now)

But I am having trouble understanding how to configure the redirect_uri on the Spring Boot app side, e.g. currently it is being set to "/sso/login" by default in [image: the query parameters].
If I manually change the URL to have a different value for redirect_uri (one that is valid & entered in the Keycloak Admin console client configuration, for ex. "/customers"), then after authentication is completed, the "/customers" uri is attempted but [image: responds with 302] and redirects to [image: "/sso/login" with a 403 error] and the error page is displayed. 
 Keycloak logs:

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-738) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=TestingRealm2, clientId=login-app, userId=4f1dab2b-81dc-4bdf-9c2c-6e4587a04eba, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=276ab439-a093-4859-8bd4-7938a3525227, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

(Also in cases like this (some sort of error during authentication) I would like to have a specific redirect configured for errors or failures instead of "/sso/login?error=....". Is this possible?)

Note: If I attempt to access the "/customers" resource, I get redirected to Keycloak auth page, I complete it, then I am successfully redirected back to "/customers" on client app, however the "redirect_uri" value still points to "/sso/login".

Note: I created my Spring Boot app based on this [image: example].

Comment: your call redirects to /sso/login URL so that keycloak can start the authentication flow. You don't have to add /sso/login as a redirect URI

Comment: @Abhijeet i have only added "/sso/login" as a redirect URI, because it does not work otherwise (as mentioned in the post). If i were to remove it from the redirect URI's in Keycloak admin console, then when I would initiate the authentication flow, i would instantly get an error page with "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri". I assume this is because the Spring Boot app sets the query parameter redirect_uri to ".../sso/login" by default. This is what my question was about - how do I change this on the Spring Boot app side.